# How to add different suffixes to even/odd numbered lines on Sublime Text?

Tags: regex, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I'm using Sublime Text 3 for mostly formatting some data values with regex. I want to add different suffixes varies by even/odd numbered lines or by values. To be more precise, I want to add language code suffixes to values in a pattern as below:

```
value_1_en
value_1_fr
value_2_en
value_2_fr
value_3_en
value_3_fr
...
```

Thanks for your answer in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this in 2 steps. Please note that I have tested the regex in notepad++ (not in sublime).

First use Regex: `([\w_]+)(?=\r*\n*\1)` and replace with `\1_en`  [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wzmRQt/1/)

Then use Regex: `^(?!.*_en)(.*)$` and replace with `\1_fr`  [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zli65l/1)

Comment: It works in Sublime Text too. I'm pretty beginner at this even so I've got your reasoning on this. Thank you very much for your answer.